# Illustrating Karesh Kuhn Tucker with two non-nonnegativy constraints binding

Tags: optimization

I'm teaching Karesh-Kuhn-Tucker, and looking for papers, ideally in the fields of development, agricultural or environmental economics, and ideally in good journals, that I can use to illustrate the situation where the KKT conditions are satisfied with two contraints (*not* nonnegativity) are binding.    [image: blue circled corner solution]

The corner solution circled in blue illustrates what I mean.  Would anybody be able to suggest some?    Thanks very muich indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only two or three papers spontaneously come to my mind, they are not very recent (but quite seminal papers, useful to find further newest contributions):

Lee, Lung-Fei, and Mark M. Pitt, 1986, "Microeconometric Demand System with Binding Nonnegativity Constraints: The Dual Approach," Econometrica, 54, 1237–1242.
Lee, Lung-Fei and Mark M. Pitt, 1987, "Microeconometric models of rationing, imperfect markets, and non-negativity constraints," Journal of Econometrics, 36, 89-110.

Here is a more recent contribution:
Golan, Amos, et al. “Estimating a Demand System with Nonnegativity Constraints: Mexican Meat Demand,” The Review of Economics and Statistics, vol. 83, no. 3, 2001, pp. 541–550.

Comment: Thank you very much!